# Dictionary is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a large code, in which I needed to use this function inside, the function is pretty simple, it takes (`dict`, `int`) as arguments and inside it and creates a dictionary, which we have to initialize when the program runs.
The error happens exactly in the line `candidate["permutation"] = stochastic_swipe(best["permutation"])` I have already checked that `Best` is not None, and The None object here is `candidate`.

```
def ILS(best, maxIter):
    while maxIter>0:
        candidate ={}
        candidate["permutation"] = stochastic_swipe(best["permutation"])
        candidate["cost"] = total_cost(candidate["permutation"])
        if candidate["cost"] < best["cost"]:
            best = candidate
        maxIter -=1

    return best
```

`Best`is being passed like that 
`{'permutation': [0, 799, 334, 816], 'cost': 19208.973827922397}`

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Perhaps a different error, but if arguments are `(list, int)`, this means best is a list, so you can't have best["cost"] or best["permutation"].

Comment: The error could very well be with the code calling `localSearch()`. Please [edit] your question and include the full traceback you're getting — or better yet, the full code if it's not too long.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a rabbit hole, because it's not enough to tell if you're passing a `best` argument equal to `None` (because we still don't know what the `perturbation()` function is returning). It looks like `localSearch()` is being passed `None` as its first argument. Surely you can debug and verify if that is true or not…

Comment: There are two possible causes of the error on the line you indicated: Either `candidate` is `None` or `best` is — since it's not `best`, it must be former. See if you can figure out _why_ `candidate` is `None` when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are calling this function with `None` as the first argument. We can see from your code that `candidate` is always a dictionary, but until the line:

```
        best = candidate
```

is executed, `best` is just what you passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You say "best" is a list, if so you' can't access its' elements like `best["permutation"]`

My strong guess is you're passing in None as the value of best.